# Weighted voting based on user experience

Tags: voting

What are the issues of using a weighted voting system* based on the user comment score in  sites like Reddit?

<sup>* A weighted voting system is one in which the preferences of some voters carry more weight than the preferences of other voters.</sup>

*Note: The maximum value the user can assign to a comment increases logarithmically.*

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the UX issues that could arise when using a weighted voting system.

1. It may not be clear how it works and what is going on behind the scenes. (How come *my* vote didn't cancel out *her* vote? Is it because she's a girl?)
2. Votes happen independently from reputation changes which means even more ambiguity either way you choose to handle it.  (e.g. Do you change all the previous votes a user made as his reputation changes? It could be confusing if you do and confusing if you don't)
3. It may discourage new users from participating if only a handful of "old timers" can control the conversation.
4. It may also encourage new users to go along with power users even if they don't truly agree in order to gain favor/power.

Comment: I've long wondered about systems like this. From time to time I've wondered about a "bicameral" solution (as was done in the US Legislature) but haven't figured out how it could actually work. - This might actually be a good chat topic. (Been trying to increase usage of the chat area.)